# keep getting "No module named 'flask'"

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to deploy my Flask endpoint on a AWS EC2 and after successfully installing requirements.txt which I run on ElasticBeanstalk, I try to run my scrip and it gives me:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

I tried manually to install flask with:

```
pip3 install flask
```

and still does not want to compile.

Comment: And `pip list` shows the flask module? Are you running a virtual environment that doesn't have flask installed?

Answer (score -2):

I haven't used AWS EC2 yet, but try adding shebang on top #!/usr/bin/env python